# When selecting a recent file from the application context menu in windows 7, the program opens, but does not open the selected file?

Tags: windows-7, sql-management-studio

What gives?  when I mouse over sp_profileColumn.sql and left click; Management studio opens but doesn't load the file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do any of the other options work?
 
If you open Studio and then select that file does it open then?

If could be the file isn't in that location anymore and windows hasn't refreshed the view

Comment: No, it's not that simple.  Microsoft's own software doens't integrate well with their OS, i tried double clicking on a *.sql file from the desktop still same problem.

Comment: What about opening it from within the software?